# How to retrieve from a Dictionary<string, List<int>>

Tags: c#, dictionary

```
public Dictionary<string, List<double>> GetTotalLengt_VolumehofMemberUsed_AlongStaadName()
{
    var memberData = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();
    var sec_Dict = _sectionDetails.GetAllMemberIDsWithinATable();

    string _stdName = "";
    double _memLength = 0.0; double _totalMemLength = 0.0;
    double _memVolume = 0.0; double _totalMemVolume = 0.0;

    foreach(string s in sec_Dict.Keys)
    {
        foreach(int n in sec_Dict.Values)
        {
            _memLength = this.Getlengthofmember(n);
            _totalMemLength = _memLength + _totalMemLength;
            _memVolume = this.GetVolumeofmember(n);
            _totalMemVolume = _memVolume + _totalMemVolume;
        }
    }

    this.STAAD_NAME = _stdName;
    this.TOTAL_MEMBER_LENGTH = _totalMemLength;
    this.TOTAL_MEMBER_VOLUME = _totalMemVolume;

    List<double> list = new List<double>();
    list.Add(this.TOTAL_MEMBER_LENGTH);
    list.Add(this.TOTAL_MEMBER_VOLUME);
    memberData.Add(this.STAAD_NAME, list);
    return memberData;
}
```

This `foreach(int n in sec_Dict.Values)` is wrong in my code. Please show me that how should I fetch each `int` from the `List<int>` values in my dictionary.

Comment: Try `foreach(int n in sec_Dict[s])`

Comment: It's easy to tell you how to make the code compile. Making it do something meaningful, however, requires more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the type of each of values is `List<int>` and you want to cast it to `int`.
Use this Code:

```
foreach(string s in sec_Dict.Keys)
{
    foreach(int n in sec_Dict[s])
    {
        _memLength = this.Getlengthofmember(n);
        _totalMemLength = _memLength + _totalMemLength;
        _memVolume = this.GetVolumeofmember(n);
        _totalMemVolume = _memVolume + _totalMemVolume;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your values are `List<int>`, so you need to declare `n` as `List<int>`

Comment: I need to fetch each int from the List<int>. Please specify, how may I get that?

Answer (score 0):

The `Dictionary` which you have constructed is bit difficult to handle. For this reason Microsoft BCL team has introduced a new Collection type called `MultiValueDictionary`. Please find the below link for more details

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/08/05/multidictionary-becomes-multivaluedictionary.aspx

Comment: I am not allowed to use that.Please specify how may I fetch each int using this Dictionary<string,List<int>>.

Answer (score 0):

As your values are of type `List<int>`

you should change your foreach to:

```
 foreach (List<int> valueList in sec_Dict.Values)
 {
     foreach (int n in valueList)
     {
         _memLength = this.Getlengthofmember(n);
         _totalMemLength = _memLength + _totalMemLength;
         _memVolume = this.GetVolumeofmember(n);
         _totalMemVolume = _memVolume + _totalMemVolume;
     }
 }
```